# SQL Selecting and Returning Data Based on Pattern

Tags: sql, select, pattern-matching, sql-server-2000

At my office, one of the tables we use keeps track of our Order Numbers.  The problem is that the employees don't enter the number consistantly into the database field.
Some of the examples are listed:

```
  '7-26-13 543006-27031', '345009-27031', 'KWYD-863009-27031'.
```

I need to to find a way to return  just the 'nnnnnn-nnnnn' substring
no matter where in the field it is.  Most of the time, this pattern is at the end of the field, but that is not always the case.  I've already limited the data records to just those with that pattern using a LIKE expression in my WHERE clause, but I have no idea how to best return just that pattern as a column.

---

Edit:

We are still using SQL Server 2000

What I'm looking to do is along the lines of:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(VendorOrderNo, ??, 12) AS OrderNo
FROM Orders
WHERE VendorOrderNo LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

Comment: You need to add a tag to state what database your using and some sample data illustrating possible inputs and their correct output would help.

Comment: Sounds like you need a CASE statement but as Alex wrote, you'll need to give examples to get an answer

Comment: I agree with Alex and TwoLegs.  If this is ultimately going to be part of an UPDATE statement designed to correct the bad data entry, you might provide some information in that regard as well.

Comment: I've changed the examples from generics to actual data.  I also added a semi-query of what I'm looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select 'nnnnnn-nnnnn' as employeeid 
  from table 
 where employees like'%nnnnnn-nnnnn'
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you adjust your data first, you can give this a try (its for MYSQL)

```
SELECT * FROM your_table_name WHERE order_number REGEXP '[0-9]+-[0-9]+';
```

**[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7b4e/7)**